# Major ghosting in dual screen

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, compiz

So I have the following setup: Arch Linux with Compiz as stand-alone window manager.  Whenever I use the dual screen setup and drag windows into the VGA outputted screen I get major ghosting.  Last I saw this level of ghosting was in XP days.

So is there something I can do to remedy this situation?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean if I use incorrect terms here :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually ghosting - Ghosting implies a fainter offset signal due to limitations of the graphics card or monitor, it looks more like a problem with the redraw rate - for example using a very slow display driver - like a slow, generic Frame Buffer driver rather then something appropriate for your card.

Compiz is for "3d" and fancy stuff (Transparency jumps to mind), and requires graphics acceleration to work well.   The solution is to find an appropriate driver for your graphics card and install it (and how you do that will depend on your graphics card).  The correct driver makes differences of orders-of-magnitude.

Comment: Well its a intel based laptop system (B940 CPU or some such) and I installed the intel drivers from the Arch repos so I assume the drivers are correct.  I wonder if there is some sort of X configuration I can tweak to accomodate dual screen or is this a limitation of my hardware?